# SQL Server date parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to build a report to get the the first 3 months of production for a couple of agents, the problem is every agent has a different opened datefor example:

```
fAgent   fOpenDate   fMonth1   fMonth2   fMonth3
  A      2017-05-01    20        100       50
  B      2017-02-20    15        25        70
  C      2017-11-15    20        15        55
```

- For Agent A the first three months would be June-17, July-17, Aug-17
- For Agent B the first three months would be March-17, April-17, May-17
- For Agent C the first three months would be December-17, January-18, February-18

I though maybe use Declare to a certain @Date and delimit that way the query but I am not able to structure it.

Help please?

Comment: What results do you want?   Doesn't the data show what you want?  What is "datefor"?

Comment: I wanto to show the production for 3 months ahead the openeddate only, but the script that im using has declare so I want a way t identify the opened date for each of the agents and get the production for that upcoming month                       
                 @DateBeg date = '2017-01-01'
  ,@DateEnd date = '2018-04-30'

Comment: Can you post the SQL you already have?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select t.*,
       dateadd(month, 1, fOpenDate) as Month1,
       dateadd(month, 2, fOpenDate) as Month2,
       dateadd(month, 3, fOpenDate) as Month3
. . .
```

Comment: Im trying to get the actual procution depending on the Opened date by agent, so im limiting my parameters to get the first 3 months of production for these three agents